# Grabbing the ID number in a blade

Tags: php, forms, laravel, routes

I have a route that takes me to my item page.

```
Route::get('/items/{item}', 'ItemsController@show');
```

In this page I have a form if the form is not filled out properly it will redirect to the forms method which currently is

```
action="/items"
```

How can I access that same {item} id number while in the blade?

Edit: Here is the Controller code

```
public function index()
{
  $item = Post::get();
  $price = $item->price;

  return view('item');
}

public function show(Item $item)
{
  return view('item', compact('item'));
}
```

Comment: Please show the controller code and the relevant form code.

Comment: The relevant form code should be <form action="/items"></form>

Comment: Great. Why are you showing a form for a specific item but posting it to an end point that is generic and not specific to that item? is it because you're storing the ID in a hidden input field? Where's the controller code? We ask these questions because we require clarification to diagnose and assist. Please oblige so we can assist you better.

Comment: I wasn't about to copy all the controller code into a comment... but the only part of the form that is relevant is the action in my mind so I put that into a comment for you quickly. To answer your question more correctly I know this isn't the most ideal way to accomplish the goal but.... School haha. So we have an item we can add to a "cart" and in the cart you have to fill out a form. But if the form was filled out incorrectly I want to push them back to the page with errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning `compact('item')` which gives you `$item` in your blade template.

You can use it within blade syntax, just like this:

```
{{ $item->id }}
```

Comment: Ah I was very close I forgot I needed to reference the id as well I tried {{ $item }} thanks! I am now getting an error however. Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

Comment: @LandonCall This indicates that the route is a `GET` request, because you have not defined the `method="POST"` on the form

Comment: OMG DUH! I do that every time. :/ Thank you again.